# awk replace column value with increment values if length equals

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I have non-standard data, which I'd like to standardise

file:

```
d101 11001
e101 9665
f101 9663
d102 11002
e102 11003
f102 11004
g102 11005
```

desired output:

```
d101 11001
e101 12001
f101 12002
d102 11002
e102 11003
f102 11004
g102 11005
```

so the logic should be, if length of column2 = 4 it should replace it with incremental numbering of a provided series: in this case 1200 is series, & 1, 2, 3 .. are increments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk -v n=12000 'length($2)==4 {$2=++n} {print}' file
d101 11001
e101 12001
f101 12002
d102 11002
e102 11003
f102 11004
g102 11005
```

Note that we first increment `n` and then assign, to use the new value. If we wanted to start printing from `12000` we would use: `$2=n++`, first assign and then increase.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl6)

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; print .words[0]~" "; put S/^ \d**4 $/{++$i + 12000}/ given .words[1];'
```

Briefly, raku is called at the command line with the `-ne` (linewise, non-autoprinting) flags. A `state` variable is declared (once and only once), for incrementing within the code. In the second statement the `.words[0]` first whitespace separated 'word' (i.e. column) is `printed` followed by a `~` tilde concatenated `" "` blank space (for separating the output columns). In the third statement the `S///` (big-S) substitution command searches for `\d**4` exactly 4 digits within `given .words[1]` (the second column). A match is replaced with `{++$i + 12000}` a computed value (curlies  denote code blocks within regexes), and returned (because `S///` big-S substitution returns the modified string).

Sample Input:

```
d101 11001
e101 9665
f101 9663
d102 11002
e102 11003
f102 11004
g102 11005
```

Sample Output:

```
d101 11001
e101 12001
f101 12002
d102 11002
e102 11003
f102 11004
g102 11005
```

https://raku.org