# awk print only modified lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, search, replace

I have file like this

```
d1000 1000
d1001 100
d1002 10
d1003 1
```

I want to modify second column where length is not equal 4.
But I want to print only lines that are modified, so original text in column 2 stays in coulmn 2, and change is printed in 3rd column with an increment to a number.

Desired Output:

```
d1001 100 1101
d1002 10  1102
d1003 1  1103
```

I'm trying along these lines, but not able to get the syntax or results

```
awk -v n=1100 '((length($2)!=4 && length($2)>0) {new=($2=++n)}; {print $1, $2, new}' file
```

Comment: So, you want to add a third column containing an incrementing variable initialized with `n`, but only print anything if the second column is not 4 characters long. What about `$7`? I don't see a 7th column here. And in your example you are replacing the text in the second column with the new column (in addition to adding the new column) although you stated it should remain unchanged. Also, you should get syntax errors from the unbalanced parentheses in your length condition ...

Comment: You can slightly modify the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702027/216907) to a recent question of yours, use `length($2)!=4` and you don't modify the existing field but you `print $0, ++n`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `print` the existing line (`$0`) and a new field like this, `,` will use the output separator between the arguments.

```
awk -v n=1100 'length($2)!=4 {print $0,++n}' file
```

Output:

```
d1001 100 1101
d1002 10 1102
d1003 1 1103
```

If you need any additional formatting of the output, you can use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) function. Here is an example for alignment:

```
$ awk -v n=1100 'length($2)!=4 {printf "%s %4s %s\n", $1, $2, ++n}' file
d1001  100 1101
d1002   10 1102
d1003    1 1103
$ awk -v n=1100 'length($2)!=4 {printf "%s %-4s %s\n", $1, $2, ++n}' file
d1001 100  1101
d1002 10   1102
d1003 1    1103
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v k=1100 '{if(length($2) !=4  && length($2)>0){k=k+1;print $1,$2,k }}' file.txt
```

output

```
d1001 100 1101
d1002 10 1102
d1003 1 1103
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; if .words[1].match( /^ \d**0..3 $/ ) { print .words~" "; put ++$i + 1100 };'
```

This question is similar to a recent question, and you can slightly modify that question's Raku answer.

Briefly (compared to the previous question), ask `if .words[1]` the second column can match to a string that contains nothing other than `\d**0..3` zero-to-three digits, and if so, print out all `.words`, followed by a third column that returns the `$i` counter, starting from a basal value of `1100` incremented via `++`.

Sample Input:

```
d1000 1000
d1001 100
d1002 10
d1003 1
```

Sample Output:

```
d1001 100 1101
d1002 10 1102
d1003 1 1103
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703436/227738
https://raku.org